# how to remove the previous label shadow

Tags: python, tkinter

my code should work like this:

1. when I click the start button it will show a group of four words that are constantly changing.
2. At the moment I click the stop button, the program will stop immediately and the four words in the screen will be the *lucky* words.
3. My problem is this: as the words change very fast, the new words do not replace the old words completely, and the shadow of the old words are still visible. How can I remove the shadow?

[image]

```
import tkinter
import random

words='''ant baboon badger bat bear beaver camel cat clam cobra cougar 
coyote crow deer dog
donkey duck eagle ferret fox frog goat goose hawk lion lizardllama mole 
monkey moose mouse
mule newt otter owl panda parrot pigeon python rabbit ram rat raven rhino 
salmon seal shark
sheep skunk sloth snake spider stork swan tiger toad trout turkey turtle 
weasel whale wolf
wombat zebra
'''.split()
a=[]
label=dict.fromkeys(['a','b','c','d','e'],tkinter.Label)
after_id=None
root=tkinter.Tk()
frame=tkinter.Frame(root)
frame.pack()



def first_price():
    global after_id
    a.clear()
    while len(a)<5:
        rand=random.randint(0,len(words)-1)
        if rand not in a:
           a.append(rand)

   for i in range(0,len(a)):
       label[i] = tkinter.Label(frame, text=words[a[i]])
       label[i].grid(row=i,)
   after_id = frame.after(100,first_price)




def stop():
   global after_id
   if after_id:
       print(after_id)
       print(a)
       frame.after_cancel(after_id)
       after_id=None


button_1= tkinter.Button(frame,text='Start',bg='red',fg='yellow',command=first_price)
button_2 =tkinter.Button(frame,text="Stop",bg='yellow',fg='red',command=stop)

button_1.grid(row=6,)
button_2.grid(row=7)


root.title('Luck Draw')
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Simple answer is defining a frame subclass and simply overwrite it with another object.

Answer (score 0):

in tkinter you have the forget method, if you are using .grid you use .grid_forget(), i don't rebember very well, but in .pack is .pack_forget() i guess and .place don't have a method (I guess). I make somes changes in your code, but this maybe will work

```
a=[]
labelList = []
after_id=None

root=tkinter.Tk()
frame=tkinter.Frame(root)
frame.pack()

def first_price():
    global after_id, labelList
    a = []
    while len(a)<5:
        rand=random.randint(0,len(words)-1)
        if rand not in a:
            a.append(rand)
    if labelList != 0: # this is for no delete the firsts words
        for i in labelList: # run a variable on the label list
            i.grid_forget() # call the .grid_forget() of the labels of list
    labelList = [] # return to nothing
    for i in range(0,len(a)):
        label = tkinter.Label(frame, text=words[a[i]]) # create your label
        label.grid(row=i,) # place label
        labelList.append(label) #add the label object in the label list
    after_id = frame.after(100,first_price)
```

Comment: thank you so much, this is the first question i have asked on stackoverflow.com and it has been perfectly resolved

Comment: it's nothing ^^, I'm new here too. I like so much make things with tkinter, if you need some help i can help any time if I know do